# Lines with dots and density changing with zoom

Tags: grease-pencil

[[image: Bug with grease pencil lines1]
Hi,
Why my line are doted like that in grease pencil ? It does that only with textured brushes, also density change depending on zoom, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change dots stroke to solid stroke.

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks, but it erase the texture of the brush, it seems blender is not capable to make circles for exemple with textured brushes. I am looking for textured brush like the one in toon boom who are vectors.